# Undefined symbol when loading a shared library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

In my program I need to load a shared library dynamically with `dlopen()`. Both the program and the shared library are successfully cross-compiled for an `ARM` architecture with the cross-compiler installed on my `x86`. However, whenever the program tries to load the library at run time on `ARM`, it fails giving this error:

> undefined symbol: _dl_hwcap

I cannot find the culprit of this error.

Let me give details on how the shared library (`libmyplugin.so`) is built on `x86` first. I use the `g++` cross-compiler as below:

```
/home/me/arm/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -c -s -fPIC -o build/module1.o module1.cpp
/home/me/arm/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -c -s -fPIC -o build/module2.o module2.cpp
/home/me/arm/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o dist/libmyplugin.so build/module1.o build/module2.o --sysroot /home/me/arm/sysroot/ -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lX11 -lXext /home/me/arm/libstatic.a -shared -s -fPIC
```

Please pay attention to the following notes:

1. `module1.cpp` and `module2.cpp` are my source code files.
2. `libstatic.a` is a big archive of object `.o` files implementing the stuff directly invoked/referenced by `module1.cpp` and `module2.cpp`. These object files have been compiled by others for the same ARM architecture as mine, with the same compiler flags, but using a slightly more updated `g++` compiler (`v4.9` instead of my `v4.8.3`). Unfortunately, I have no control on the building of these objects.
3. `--sysroot /home/me/arm/sysroot/` represents the remote filesystem of my `ARM OS` from which the local `g++` cross-compiler can take the native libraries while linking.
4. `-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lX11 -lXext`: these flags are required to force the dynamic loader to load the `X11` libraries present on the system when my shared library is loaded by the program. In particular, `--no-as-needed` is required because the `X11` libraries are NOT directly referenced by `module1.o` and `module2.o`; on the contrary the `X11` libraries are referenced by the static library only.

Note that all the above setup works on `x86`. It's just that I don't understand what is the reason of the `_dl_hwcap` symbol not resolved when the program tried to load the library on `ARM`.

Do you have any idea how to investigate this issue?

Comment: The cross-toolchain will have its own standard libraries and will use them by default unless you mess with path options (I think) - do those match the versions on the device?

Comment: @Notlikethat, I also suspect that the cross-toolchain I am using does not exactly match the compiler that was used to build the system libraries. But I have never had such problems so far.

Answer (score 10):

There are a myriad of things that could be problematic, but here are four avenues of exploration.  I am concentrating on the -shared in your link line, but the last item addresses that as well.
(A nice HOWTO on shared libraries is here: 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

a) Check your environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Since you aren't using RPATH to the linker (RPATH embeds a full path to the .so so you can find it at runtime), then the only way the linker can find your code is to search the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. 
Make sure the .so or .0 you want is in the path.

b) Use the UNIX utility 'nm' to search .so (shared objects) and .a files for that symbol.  For example, 'nm -D /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so' will show all dynamic symbols
in the libpython.so, and you can look for symbols of interest:
For example, Is 'initgc' defined or used in libpython?

```
% nm -D /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so | grep initgc
000003404300cf0 T initgc
```

The 'T' means TEXT or, yes, it is defined there.  See if you can find the symbol in the module of interest using grep and nm.  (A 'U' means undefined, which means it is defined in another module).

c) Another useful tool is 'ldd'.  It shows all dynamic libraries that the library you are looking on depends on.  For example:

```
% ldd /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa49ff000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000033f0200000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000033f0600000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00000033fea00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000033f0a00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000033efe00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033efa00000)
```

If it can't find a library (because it's not on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or wasn't specified in the RPATH), the library will turn up empty.

d) I am a little worried from your link line of seeing a '.a' file with a -shared option.  Some compilers/linkers cannot use a '.a' (archive) file to create a '.so' file.  '.so' files usually have to made from other '.so' files or '.o' files that have been compiled with -fPIC.

I would recommend (if you can), recompile /home/me/arm/libstatic.a so that it's a .so.  If you can't do, you might have to make your final output a '.a' file as well.  (In other words, get rid of the -shared command line option).

In summary: Check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, use nm and ldd to look around at your .a and .so files, but I think the end result is that you may not be able to combine .so and .a files.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/ -name *.so -exec bash -c "nm --defined-only {} 2>/dev/null | grep <your symbol> && echo {}" ;
```

This command is designed to search for files with the .so extension in the home directory and then examine each of those files for a specific symbol (_dl_hwcap in your case) using the nm and grep commands. If the symbol is found in a file, the filename is displayed. After identifying the file, you can include it in your configuration file.