# Failure to link v8 in a native Dart extension

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, v8

I am trying to use v8 in a [Dart native extension](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-vm/native-extensions).

The [v8 getting started guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Embedding) says to compile the hello world example like this.

```
g++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello-world -Wl,--start-group \
out.gn/x64.release/obj/{libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform,libsampler},\
third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n},src/inspector/libinspector}.a \
-Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
```

Dart says to compile native extensions like so:

```
g++ -fPIC -I{path to SDK include directory} -DDART_SHARED_LIB -c sample_extension.cc

gcc -shared -m32 -Wl,-soname,libsample_extension.so -o libsample_extension.so sample_extension.o
```

This is the hybrid I came up with

```
g++ -fPIC -I{path to SDK include directory} -Iinclude -DDART_SHARED_LIB -c sample_extension.cc -std=c++0x

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsample_extension.so -Wl,--start-group out.gn/x64.release/obj/{libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform,libsampler},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n},src/inspector/libinspector}.a -Wl,--end-group  -o libsample_extension.so sample_extension.o -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
```

However, while trying to run my application, I get an error stating that v8 is not linked properly.

```
dart: symbol lookup error: /mnt/c/Users/zvacu/Documents/Code/Dart/require/libsample_extension.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V828InitializeICUDefaultLocationEPKcS2_
```

I can manage to link it properly when using the hello world example provided.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little research it seems like the problem it is on the -shared property on the second command. You need to pay attention with C++ and shared libraries, so check if your library get's all its dependencies by:

```
ldd /mnt/c/Users/zvacu/Documents/Code/Dart/require/libsample_extension.so
```

After this you will get a list of all dependencies, then you will need to search if there is anyone missing.

If this does not answer your question, see this related answer:

[Undefined symbol when loading a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175308/undefined-symbol-when-loading-a-shared-library)